# Нужна ли запятая?

Tags: пунктуация

Нужна ли запятая перед "как" в этом предложении?
"Надежность понимают(,) как возможность выполнения элементом, системой и т.п. требуемой функции в предлагаемых условиях в течение заданного интервала времени".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Здесь ***как*** в значении в "качестве", поэтому запятая не нужна.